# Libgdx GWT WebSocket Object Serialization

Tags: java, javascript, gwt, serialization, websocket

**BACKGROUND:** I'm working on a side-project (game) with goals of learning [LibGDX](https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx) (using only *JavaScript/HTML5 deployment*) and figuring out **client/server communication in this environment** (a seemingly unpopular combination).

**NETWORK COMMUNICATION:** Coming from a [Kryonet](https://github.com/EsotericSoftware/kryonet) background ([and since Kryonet is incompatible with GWT](http://www.badlogicgames.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=11&t=19645)), I have landed on [gwt-web-sockets-1.0.0](https://github.com/rzschech/gwt-comet/tree/master/src/net/zschech/gwt/websockets/client) (a Java GWT wrapper for JavaScript WebSockets) for network communication (which is perfect for me since I'm really only comfortable in Java).

With use of the gwt-web-sockets-1.0.0 library I can effectively communicate from client -> server using the follwing native call:

[image]

**PROBLEM:**  I am skeptical of the scalability of the above send() method. Kryonet serializes classes and supports sending respective serialized instances (ex: sending a *Player* instance). With the above implementation, all I'm really given to work with is sending data as type **String**. I have found another JS wrapper implementation by [sksamuel](https://github.com/sksamuel/gwt-websockets) in which he implements practically the same thing as gwt-web-sockets-1.0.0 except he takes it one step further and adds [binary support](https://github.com/sksamuel/gwt-websockets#binary-support).

**QUESTION:** Ideally, I'd like to be able to implement something similar to Kryonet - serializing and sending objects natively through Java (GWT-compatible). If that isn't possible, I'm guessing the next best solution would be to add another layer above the described `send(String data)` and/or `send(byte[] data)` methods for network communication. Perhaps something like `send(Serializer.convert(data))` -- where data is my *Player* object that is converted into either String or byte[] which is the expected argument of the native send() method) that is compatible with GWT.

As always, thanks for any help you can provide.